# Extracting first_name and last_name from full_name in Oracle

Tags: oracle

1. If input is comma separated then store the first part in LAST_NAME and second part in FIRST_NAME.
2. If comma is not present then store the name in LAST_NAME

Can you please help me in achieving the #2 in oracle?
In my approach am unable to store the full_name in last_name column if there is no comma.

Input :
1. FULL_NAME = "MIKE,MYERS"
2. FULL_NAME = "KFC"

Output :

> ```
>  SELECT SUBSTR('FULL_NAME', 0, INSTR('1,2', ',') - 1) LAST_NAME,  
>         SUBSTR('FULL_NAME', INSTR('1,2', ',', -1) + 1) FIRST_NAME   FROM DUAL
>
>   **LAST_NAME**    **FIRST_NAME**
>     MIKE             MYERS
>
>   **LAST_NAME**    **FIRST_NAME**
>                      KFC
> ```

Comment: `case when instr(full_name, ',') = 0 then full_name else substr(full_name, ...) end`

Comment: Since you need two separate columns, I think you would need two CASE statements. See my answer.

Comment: you'll quickly find that a full name field will contain all kinds of formats (FML  L,FM Suffixes, punctuation, comments/garbage, etc).  Probably best to create a function to handle this, rather than a bunch of cases within the SQL itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need two separate **columns**, I think you would need two **CASE** statements.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT 'MIKE,MYERS' str FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 'KFC' str FROM dual
  5    )
  6  SELECT
  7    CASE
  8      WHEN instr(str, ',') <> 0
  9      THEN SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str, ',', 1) - 1)
 10      ELSE str
 11    END LAST_NAME,
 12    CASE
 13      WHEN instr(str, ',') <> 0
 14      THEN SUBSTR(str, INSTR(str, ',', 1) +1)
 15      ELSE NULL
 16    END FIRST_NAME
 17  FROM DATA
 18  /

LAST_NAME  FIRST_NAME
---------- ----------
MIKE       MYERS
KFC

SQL>
```